# Inserting view between two other views

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm programming for IOS objective c for a long time now, and still at situations like so, it feels insane for me to start calculating distances each time I'm performing a simple UI action as so:

Say I have a page with a few labels:

```
NAME : MATAN
MUSIC : TECHNO
AGE : 26
```

Now in some specific cases, I would like to insert one more label between "MUSIC" and "AGE".

Normally I would check the height of the new label, and move the "AGE" label down by code.

This is CRAZY that I didn't find yet a better way than this, because when dealing with more complex views, this becomes HARD!

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I would suggest put your extra label and set it to hidden = YES, then u can manipulate with it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somone mentioned using constraints.  This should get you pointed in the right direction for that kind of thing

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];

label1.text = @"NAME : MATAN";
label2.text = @"AGE : 26";

[self.view addSubview:label1];
[self.view addSubview:label2];

[label1 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];
[label2 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label1, label2);

[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[label1]-20-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
[self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[label2]-20-|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];
NSArray * vertConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[label1]-10-[label2]" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary];

[self.view addConstraints:vertConstraint];

dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 5 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

    UILabel *label3 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label3.text = @"MUSIC : TECHNO";
    [label3 setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints: NO];

    [self.view addSubview:label3];

    NSDictionary * viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(label1, label2, label3);

   [self.view removeConstraints:vertConstraint];

    [self.view addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-20-[label3]|" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary]];

    NSArray * newVertConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-10-[label1]-10-[label3]-10-[label2]" options:0 metrics: 0 views:viewsDictionary];

    [self.view addConstraints:newVertConstraint];

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you put it all in a UITableView, which is designed for exactly this kind of stuff, and has mechanism to insert/remove cells..

Comment: Thanks for the response! This is a interesting answer, So do you actually build build all your views as table view? Even if the design doesn't look like a list at all? Only so you can implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: @PiratM yep, exactly.  A tableView can only be 150px wide or 200 tall or whatever, no problem.  Can go inside a UIPopover, all kinds of approaches.  Still looks like some kind of a list to me ;)

Comment: indeed, `UITableView` gives you an easy interface to design your interface. also, _scrolling_ comes for free with this approach.

Answer (score 1):

UITableView for this use is kind of overkill given the amount of boilerplate code you have to add. A better solution is to use two overlapping container view controllers, each contains the proper fixed layout of the required labels. You can programmatically enable and disable the two containers respectively. See Apple guide below for some examples:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html

Answer (score 0):

You could always use tableViews to make it more easy.

If not then read something about Constraints. Maybe you already know about it. But they are a big help if you can do it properly.

[Read more about constraints here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)